# How to display created dynamic attibute into the customer array?

Tags: attributes, customer, array, dynamic

We already created dynamic attribute and that attribute display on the admin side Account information tab of admin.

But when we need to add some value on that feild at that time we find that, that dynamic field not in customer array.

How to fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: show us the code how you provide the selected values

Comment: Selected value from the dropdown list ( country code).

Comment: how are country codes dynamic?

Comment: No, we set static as per requirement but all code into the dropdown.

Comment: I think I speak for more people when I say that I don't understand what you are doing or want to do. please provide more information and CODE in your question

Comment: We create one dynamic attribute for the customer ( country code ).
Now we need to store Country code from the signup page.

Comment: simple is that `visible' => true,` and use the **attribute_code** as the field name. magento autosave the value.

Comment: @QaisarSatti => Yes, we did this yesterday and now working and saved value properly.

Comment: I added as a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple is that add this in attribute array `visible' => true,` and use the **attribute_code** as the field name. magento autosave the value.